# SSRS 2016 Sum time values represented as string

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2016

I have a column, showing time (hours (may be > 24) : minutes : seconds) which is represented as string in my dataset.

```
40:02:20
365:23:30
12:00:59
23:59:59
```

I need to get the sum, which in this case would be:

```
574:59:59 or 24.3:59:59 (any of this output is ok)
```

I tried to use the expression below, but it gives me the error, because I need to cast the time value somehow.

`=TimeSpan.FromTicks(Sum(Fields!time.Value))`

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Is this value stored in the database as a string or is it being transformed to a string from say, SECONDS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't answer your question specifically but best practice is to store duration in seconds or StartDates and EndDates as a `DATETIME` or similar, DATATYPE and then use `DATEDIFF` to calculate duration.

Then in the SSRS report you can use this expression to display as HH:MM:SS

```
=Floor(Sum(Fields!someSeconds.Value) / 3600) & ":" & Format(DateAdd("s", Sum(Fields!someSeconds.Value), "00:00"), "mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following custom code in your report

```
Public Dim hours As Integer
Public Dim minutes As Integer
Public Dim seconds As Integer

Public Function sumTime( ByVal s As String) As String

Dim substrings() As String =  s.Split(":")

hours = hours + Cint(substrings(0))
minutes = minutes + Cint(substrings(1))
seconds = seconds + Cint(substrings(2))

minutes = minutes + (Math.floor(seconds / 60))
seconds = seconds mod   60

hours = hours + (Math.floor(minutes / 60))
minutes = minutes mod 60


Return s

End Function
```

The function takes as parameter the time string, splits it in hours, minutes and seconds and creates a total of each one of them.

You can call the function inserting the following expression (image: blue font color)

```
= Code.sumTime(Fields!time1.Value)
```

For the total(image: green font color) you can use an expression like

```
= Cstr(Code.hours) & ":" & Right("0" & Cstr(Code.minutes),2) & ":" &  Right("0" & Cstr(Code.seconds),2)
```

[image]

[image]